# How set item checkbox when i click on element span which have this checkbox?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Me need set item checkbox when i click on element span which have this checkbox.

Code:

```
<script>
$('.CheckMemberClassList').bind('click',function(){
    $('.CheckMemberClassList').removeClass('MemberClassActive').addClass('MemberClassInactive');
    $(this).removeClass('MemberClassInactive').addClass('MemberClassActive');
    });
</script>


<span class="MemberClass1 MemberClassActive CheckMemberClassList">
<input type="radio" name="MemberClassList" id="MemberClassList1" value="1" checked="checked">
Text One
</span>

<span class="MemberClass2 MemberClassInactive CheckMemberClassList">
<input type="radio" name="MemberClassList" id="MemberClassList2" value="2">
Text Two
</span>

<span class="MemberClass3 MemberClassInactive CheckMemberClassList">
<input type="radio" name="MemberClassList" id="MemberClassList3" value="3">
Text Tree
</span>
```

Tell me please how i need make its in this code?

Comment: I think you probably need to use `<label for="formElementID">...</label>` tags instead of `<span>...</span>`. This will make text associated with your radio buttons clickable, as if the corresponding radio button was clicked. [Label tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp). If I'm right, then no javascript is neccessary.

Comment: no problem. I forgot about the search )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.CheckMemberClassList').bind('click',function(){
    $('.CheckMemberClassList').removeClass('MemberClassActive').addClass('MemberClassInactive');
    $(this).removeClass('MemberClassInactive').addClass('MemberClassActive');
    $(this).find('input:radio').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hMYtg/

Jquery .prop() Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Still too complex. (a) Use `<label>` tags look after the radio buttons. (b) 'MemberClassInactive' is unnecessary - the inactive state can  handled in every respect by the absence of 'MemberClassActive'. See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ByCgK/)**

Answer (score 9):

change your `<span>`s to `<label>` with a `for=` attribute matching the ID of your input, like so:

```
<label for="checkbox1">Click Me!</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2GbPS/

Actually, since you have your checkbox inside the span, this will work:

```
<label>
<input type="checkbox">
Click Me!
</label>
```

(fiddle updated)

Works with radios too!

```
<label>
<input type="radio">
Click Me!
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do you want a checkbox or a radio input? Your code is a radio input.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YvrSf/2/) showing what you require

You need the following javascript:

```
$('span').click(
    function() {
        var cb = $(this).find(":radio")[0];

        if (!$(cb).attr("checked")) {
            $(cb).attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $(cb).removeAttr("checked");
        }
    }
);

$('span input').click(
    function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
});​
```