# Toggle checkbox checked attribute without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, toggle, togglebutton

I have seen similar questions such as "[How do I toggle an element's class in pure JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880890/how-do-i-toggle-an-elements-class-in-pure-javascript)", but this question refers to attributes instead.

I have a checkbox like so:

```html
<span class="newsletter-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" id="newsletter" checked> Sign up to the newsletter as well - recieve new posts in your inbox
</span>
```

How do I make it so that when anywhere in `.newsletter-checkbox` (including the text) is clicked, it toggles the checkbox `checked` attribute?

Comment: Could i suggest something very simple, just use label tag: https://jsfiddle.net/wggofhhf/ ?

Comment: @sinisake Wow cool, I never realized you could do that! Make it an answer and I'll accept now...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12850547/295783

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use this:

```js
function toggleCheckbox() {
  var checkbox = document.getElementById('newsletter');
  checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
}
```

```html
<span class="newsletter-checkbox" onclick="toggleCheckbox()"><input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" id="newsletter" checked> Sign up to the newsletter as well - recieve new posts in your inbox</span>
```

(based off [Toggle a boolean in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604409/toggle-a-boolean-in-javascript))